# Sabre: GetReservation equivalent to TravelItineraryRead

Tags: sabre

I'm implementing GetReservation because TravelItineraryRead will soon be deprecated.

When creating a PNR, I get successful responses of GetReservation, but when I try to query the previously created PNR, Sabre WS rejects with "*Viewership is restricted for the PNR, caused by [Viewership is restricted for the PNR (Unsupported security check), code: 700102, severity: MODERATE*"

I'm connecting to Sabre WS via SOAP, in test endpoint https://sws-tls.cert.sabre.com.

The RQ I'm sending is:

```
<GetReservationRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19" Version="1.19.0">
  <Locator>XWYZA</Locator>
  <RequestType>Stateless</RequestType>
  <ReturnOptions PriceQuoteServiceVersion="3.2.0">
    <SubjectAreas>
      <SubjectArea>FULL</SubjectArea>
    </SubjectAreas>
    <ViewName>Full</ViewName>
    <ResponseFormat>STL</ResponseFormat>
  </ReturnOptions>
</GetReservationRQ>
```

I've tried with others Views and SubjectAreas, but I always get that response, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to send RequestType: Stateful instead of Stateless

```
<GetReservationRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19" Version="1.19.0">
  <Locator>KDQPNP</Locator>
  <RequestType>Stateful</RequestType>
  <ReturnOptions PriceQuoteServiceVersion="3.2.0">
    <SubjectAreas>
      <SubjectArea>FULL</SubjectArea>
      <SubjectArea>PRICE_QUOTE</SubjectArea>
    </SubjectAreas>
    <ViewName>Full</ViewName>
    <ResponseFormat>STL</ResponseFormat>
  </ReturnOptions>
</GetReservationRQ>
```

Comment: Yes, the stateless version currently only allows accessing PNRs created in the IPCC. The stateful version will allow you to access PNRs in PCCs with B and C branch access, you can also use ContextChangeLLSRQ to switch to the other PCC if you wish to modify the PNR in the same session.